# Get implementer class type

Tags: c#, types, reflection, stack-trace

I have the below code

```
public abstract class abstract1
{
    public void Test1()
    {
        // << Log the caller >>
        // Environment.StackTrace gives no information about class1

        // Do something
    }
}

public class class1 : abstract1
{
}

public class Class1Test
{
    public void InvokeTest1()
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        c1.Test1();
    }
}
```

How can I get that Test1 method invoked from Class1 then abstract1 for logging purposes?

Thanks,

Comment: What does "invoked from Class1" mean? Can you give a better example? That is, show an example where it would produce some output if `Test1` is "invoked from Class1", and a different output otherwise.

Comment: "I tried MethodInfo class" Can you show what you tried?

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding of how this works. `Test1` is defined on `abstract1` and that's where it is run. The compiler just knows that a `class1` is an `abstract1` so it lets you call `Test1` from an instance of `class1`.

Comment: Thank you @Enigmativity So there is no way to detect class1 in the calling chain?

Comment: @Jimmy - There is no `class1` "in the calling chain" as the method is called directly from the instance of `class1`. But you sound like you're referring to the inheritance chain. That is quite easy to get the entire chain.

Comment: It sounds like you need `c1.GetType().BaseType` or `c1.GetType().GetMethod("Test1").DeclaringType`.

Comment: @Enigmativity It seems it is not possible I tired both and they gave me Abstract1. the only way I managed so far to get class1 by making Test1 virtual and overriding it in Class1 then just call the base. Still not really helpful as I will need to wrap all the methods in the abstract.

Comment: @Sweeper I have updated my question. Please let me know if you have more questions

Comment: @Jimmy - You're saying a lot of things that don't make sense to me, like "I will need to wrap all the methods in the abstract". Can you explain what you're trying to do at a higher level? If you could do what you are thinking you can do, what would that allow you to acheive?

Comment: @Enigmativity I tried to use your mentioned code but still got Abstract1 however when I did public class class1 : abstract1
{
public override void Test1()
{
base.Test1() // just call the base as if it was a wrapper
}
}

I got class1 then abstract1, still ugly though. I do not think there is away to achieve my original ask to get class1 without this workaround

Comment: @Jimmy - I don't understand what you're trying to do. What high-level thing are you trying to do? Don't try re-explain what you're asking. Tell me what you're hoping to achieve.

Comment: @Enigmativity When someone calls Test1, I want to log "ClassName.MethodName invoked". the value of ClassName is always Abstract1 which is not expected. the value of ClassName should be Class1. Logging the abstract class name is not useful as it could be implemented by multiple classes and I want to log the actual class that was invoked to get this method executed.

Comment: @Jimmy - Perfect. It's an extremely easy answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it's clear what you want. This does it:

```
void Main()
{
    new Class1Test().InvokeTest1();
}

public abstract class Abstract1
{
    public void Test1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Test1 called from {this.GetType().Name}");
    }
}

public class Class1 : Abstract1
{
}

public class Class1Test
{
    public void InvokeTest1()
    {
        Class1 c1 = new Class1();
        c1.Test1();
    }
}
```

That produces `Test1 called from Class1` to the console.

This works because `this.GetType()` is always the instance of the instantiated type and that doesn't change when you go up the inheritance chain.

Answer (score -3):

To get the Test1 method invoked from Class1 then abstract1 for logging purposes, you can do the following:

1. Create a new class that inherits from both Class1 and abstract1.
2. In the new class, override the Test1 method and add logging code.
3. Create an instance of the new class and call the Test1 method.

The following code shows how to do this:

```
    public class Class1Logger : Class1, abstract1
{
    public override void Test1()
    {
        // Do something
        // Add logging code here
    }
}

public class Class1Test
{
    public void InvokeTest1()
    {
        Class1Logger c1 = new Class1Logger();
        c1.Test1();
    }
}
```

When Test1 is called on the Class1Logger object, the logging code will be executed. It will allow you to register method call Test1 from Class1 and Abstract1.

An example of output

```
Class1.Test1()
abstract1.Test1()
```

The first line shows that the Test1 method was called from the Class1 class. The second line shows that the Test1 method was called from the abstract1 class.

Comment: This is ridiculous. You cannot do multiple inheritance in C#.

Comment: And the OP did not declare `Test1` as `abstract` or `virtual` so you can't `override` the method. This answer is thoroughly misleading.

Comment: @Enigmativity You are absolutely correct

Comment: @Enigmativity, it's probably an answer generated by an AI bot. The future is now...